# How to Insert a Custom Arrowhead to the Default Arrowhead List in the Stroke Dialog Box

Tags: adobe-illustrator

After finding the Arrowheads.ai file and following the required steps to create a new symbol of a custom arrowhead (which I named Arrow 40), I want to know if there's a way to add Arrow 40 to the default arrowhead list in the Stroke dialog box. The reason for this is to be able to scale the arrowhead, just like I can with the first 39 default arrowheads in the Stroke dialog box. Is there a way to add my custom arrowhead as a default to this list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom Arrowheads in Illustrator properly](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77481/how-to-create-custom-arrowheads-in-illustrator-properly)

Comment: If you've already gone through the steps of creation, you have to replace the Arrowheads.ai file with your new Arrowheads.ai file containing the new arrowhead.. and then relaunch Illustrator. [Here's a Deke McClelleand tutorial as well.](https://www.deke.com/content/creating-custom-arrowheads-in-adobe-illustrator)